# What is wrong in my CROSSTAB postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
select s.busday_of_month as day, o.net_amount as net_amount
from checks o inner join
     sequence_numbers s
     on o.as_of_date = s.as_of_date
where extract(month from o.as_of_date) = 10
```

This is the result of the above query:

[image]

I would like to transpose the above result to show data as shown below:

```
day1 | day2 | day3 | day4 | day5 | day6 ... day23
  0  |   0  |  333 |   0  |  777 | 0    ...   0
```

So I tried writing this query in postgres:

```sql
select * From Crosstab ( 'select s.busday_of_month as day, o.net_amount as net_amount from checks o inner join sequence_numbers s on o.as_of_date = s.as_of_date where extract(month from o.as_of_date) = 10 order by day','select d from generate_series(1,23) d')
```

But I get this error when I run the above query:

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: select * From Crosstab ( 'select s.busday_of_month as day, o...
                      ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 15
```

How can I accomplish my result?

Comment: 1. Does this error occur when the extension is not installed? 2. Should we install it on the client or server? 3. I was not able to find any help page on the internet which shows how to install the extension. Would you be kind enough to show me how to install the same please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I perfectly understood what you meant to do, but I got it to work this way :

```
create table checks(as_of_date date, net_amount real);
create table sequence_numbers(busday_of_month integer, as_of_date date);

insert into checks values (to_date('2019-10-03','DD/MM/YYYY', 333);
insert into checks values (to_date('2019-10-05','DD/MM/YYYY', 777);

insert into sequence_numbers values (3, to_date('03/10/2019','DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into sequence_numbers values (5, to_date('05/10/2019','DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

You first need to have a query that will return 0 for empty values, that's why I first did the join (using external join, a.k.a Left Outer Join) with the list of days :

```
select * from crosstab ($$
  SELECT 0 as header, days.day, coalesce(sum(data.net_amount),0) as tot_amount
  FROM (select day from generate_series(1,23) day) AS days
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT s.busday_of_month as day, o.net_amount as net_amount
     FROM checks o
     INNER JOIN sequence_numbers s ON o.as_of_date = s.as_of_date
     WHERE extract(month from o.as_of_date) = 10) AS data
  ON data.day = days.day
  GROUP BY days.day
  ORDER BY days.day
$$)
AS ct(
  day integer,
  d01 real,
  d02 real,
  d03 real,
  d04 real,
  d05 real,
  d06 real,
  d07 real,
  d08 real,
  d09 real,
  d10 real,
  d11 real,
  d12 real,
  d13 real,
  d14 real,
  d15 real,
  d16 real,
  d17 real,
  d18 real,
  d19 real,
  d20 real,
  d21 real,
  d22 real,
  d23 real);
```

I also used the $$ notation which makes things easier if you want to copy/paste the query to test it in psql for example.

Normally you would have to group by something, here I had to add an extra value (0 as header), otherwise following error message was shown : "The provided SQL must return 3  columns; rowid, category, and values."

Finally, the result is :

```
 day | d01 | d02 | d03 | d04 | d05 | d06 | d07 | d08 | d09 | d10 | d11 | d12 | d13 | d14 | d15 | d16 | d17 | d18 | d19 | d20 | d21 | d22 | d23
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
   0 |   0 |   0 | 333 |   0 | 777 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0
```